# invalid column name "ctn"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting an error "invalid column name "ctn""...But i named my column as "ctn" in database of datatype VarChar(100)..txtcn textbox store the value from users.Please help me to figure out an error in my code...

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.cn);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbbill (invoice, date, ctn, total, tax, grandtotal) values('"+Convert.ToInt32(txtinvoice.Text)+"','"+Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Text)+"','"+txtcn.Text+"','"+Convert.ToSingle(txtttl.Text)+"','"+Convert.ToInt32(cmtax.SelectedValue)+"','"+Convert.ToSingle(txtgrdttl.Text)+"')", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//here i am getting error....
cmd.Dispose();
```

Comment: Show the CREATE TABLE statement for tbbill.

Comment: Note that you will fail to dispose of cmd if the query above it throws an exception.  Use the `using` keyword with IDisposable objects.

Comment: I see this in the inline query : `'"**+txtcn.Text+**"'`, why you are using * here? and even if you need the stars it should before double qoutes like this: `'**"+txtcn.Text+"**'`

Comment: @AymanBarhoum OP is just highlighting the error.

Comment: Try to debug what query is composed and run it in sql server directly. And see if it works or gives error

Comment: yeah....i have runned this query with sqlserver.....it runs properly.but when i m trying with asp.net ..it shows that error.....Please help me out

Comment: i think this error comes out due to datetimepicker.please check the syntax for datetimepicker...Is that correct???

Comment: @user3526313 Why don't you use parameterized query?

Comment: i also used it....but same problem........occurs

Comment: Is the data base on a server or local?  Are you sure you're connected to the right server and database?

Comment: yes. i connected with right database i.e.local.There is no error in the connectionstring.

Comment: As Eric J specified above, show us the CREATE TABLE results for the table you created.  Otherwise it will be difficult to provide a solution.

Answer (score -4):

Run the query in your Sql Server and check if it still returns an error.

And use the `using`keyword to dispose objects automatically or use `try catch` and dispose objects in `finally` block.

Comment: This is not an answer. Questions should be posted as comments.